# Site pesado por causa de imagens

Tags: html5, css3, media-queries, jpg

Desenvolvi um site para um cliente que tem uma loja de ração, com HTML5 e CSS3, nada com backend e banco de dados, ele quer apenas divulgar os produtos, preços e etc.
A pasta /img está com 125MB e o cliente está reclamando pela demora pra carregar a página e as imagens, o que eu faço? Existem algum jeito de otimizar isso?

Comment: Qual backend vc usar? Se for possível manda seu site para me ver.

Comment: Se você não tratar as imagens ao usar no site, elas vão ter o tamanho que for enviado. Se o cliente enviar uma foto de um produto com 5Mb a página vai ficar pesada mesmo. O bom mesmo seria você redimensionar essa imagem para o tamanho correto e depois otimizá-la usando algum serviço como [Kraken.io](https://kraken.io/) ou algum aplicativo como o [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac). O melhor cenário seria ter um backend que faz estes ajustes para você ao enviar qualquer imagem para o site.

Comment: Site é esse https://casaderacoespassaroforte.000webhostapp.com 
mas nao vou usar backend, não é necessário

Comment: @fernandosavio as imagens que ele envia tem em média 70kb, mas estou otimizando colocando 
width="200px" height="200px">

Deixo elas em um tamanho relativamente bom pra visualizar e não são tão pesadas assim...

Vou otimizar com algum serviço ou app como vc falou

Comment: O tamanho da imagem e o tamanho que ela mostra na tela são duas coisas diferentes, você pode subir uma imagem de 5MB que tem 5000x2000px e usar com a tag `<img src="minha_imagem.png" width="50" height="20">`.. A imagem vai seguir tendo 5000x2000px e 5Mb, você só está mostrando ela num tamanho menor.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [Lazyload](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/). Vai carregar as imagens somente quando elas forem visíveis na tela, e não todas de uma vez. Já dá um ganho considerável de performance.

Comment: Cara, você precisa repensar a estrutura do site... Sua página carrega mais de [100MB e faz mais de 100 requisições](https://imgur.com/a/RRGTn5E?)... demorou 2 minutos pra carregar tudo. Já pensou em fazer paginação e/ou ter páginas separadas para diferentes categorias de produtos?

Comment: vou tentar o lazyload @Sam, obrigado!

Comment: boa @fernandosavio, realmente é bom eu repensar a estrutura.. Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Use miniaturas na imagem. A primeira imagem que peguei os atributos era um jpg compactado a 30% com 617kb na memória ela tem o impacto ~2.025kb sendo que são 27 linhas de 4 fotos (isso porque ignorei uma pancada de fotos que não estavam em linha de 4). Então são 66MB **por baixo** (pode estar chegando a 100MB)  para carregar sua página e impacto na memória do usuário é de 218,7MB **por baixo**, pois pode estar chegando a 300MB pois eu fiz o calculo baseado numa foto de alpiste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro é necessário verificar se o tamanho total dessas imagens se deve a **quantidade total** ou se estão **mal otimizadas**.

Além disso, pensando no lado do **usuário**, vamos supor que esse site de ração possua 200 fotos em catálogo. Com certeza em uma "olhada" na seção **Produtos** é impossível visualizar e entender os 200 itens. E imagine que um usuário está buscando o preço da ração X para o seu cachorro, para que ele precisa ver 20 produtos de pesca?

O ideal é você criar uma *estrutura de paginação* para carregar somente o necessário. E com essa estrutura você pode criar filtros de busca para melhorar ainda mais a **experiência do usuário**.

Note que estou sugerindo práticas simples que não requerem frameworks ou criação de códigos complexos.

> Experiência do usuário vai muito além de otimização e performance.

Comment: Vou seguir sua recomendação e a dos demais que comentaram acima, obrigado!

Comment: Isso ai @Arthur!